# An unfamiliar word ‘raked’

Tags: meaning, slang, errors

I had something weird happened to me not too long ago, I was texting a friend and was asking a question that isn’t super illegal but it didn’t cross any lines within the law.  To cut a long story short,  the person I thought I was texting was not who I thought she was (ended up she changed her number without telling me)  no big deal – but want happened next was a first…  halfway through our texting conversation, I was surprised to receive a text from the person who actually now had her new number and that person claimed to be a police officer and said that what I was asking was inappropriate and said my phone is now *raked* !!!!!

The point of this is to find out if anybody knows what that means

> “your phone has been raked“

Who is this person? Where they just trying to scare me or is it a real term maybe  amongst police officers? Maybe even a typo! I’m just very curious and I haven’t run across anybody that can figure it out so anybody’s help would be very much appreciated thanks for your time thanks for reading have a great day hope to hear back soon ✌️

Comment: Maybe they meant tracked.

Comment: It ran across my mind that it may have been a typo, hopefully that’s the case… So you’ve never heard the term raked used other than raking the yard LOL

Comment: That’s an odd conclusion to jump to.

Comment: Why’s that?  I don’t recall jumping to  A conclusion. Please specify…  Do you mean jumping to the conclusion that it was the police?

Comment: no, that i’ve never heard of rake outside of yard work.

Comment: I didn’t mean to insinuate that at all-I apologize,what I meant to ask was in general  if you had ever heard the term before -really didn’t mean  too offend you.  Just a general question I promise don’t  be mad at me ✌️

Comment: I don't know if or how fast they recycle phone numbers in FL but they can't do it that that fast. Especially when these numbers are often used to identify you in other online accounts. How die you know they did change the number. I think they told you they had and then pretended to be the new person.

Comment: Maybe they meant to say *baked* or *naked* and got auto-corrected to *raked*. Actually, they could have written anything.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve heard "rake" used to mean "search in an untidy way" as in:

> "Go on, have a rake through the jumble sale"

I thought it was colloquial or regional (BrE), but a quick dictionary search (American Heritage via [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Raked) shows this definition of "rake":

> v.intr.
>
> 1. To use a rake.
> 2. To conduct a thorough search: raked through the files for the misplaced letter.

That said, I’ve never seen that particular use in formal writing.

A quick look on [the Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Raked) shows it might have other colloquial meanings (including merciless teasing) but none of these are likely to come from a police officer.

TL;DR I don’t think this came from a police officer, but you might be in for some teasing.